# Mac OSX 10.8 PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, macos

There are many topics on this, but I have mysql.sock missing. I have checked /var/mysql /tmp etc I have run a search on the whole system and the file does not exist.

Can someone tell me how to regenerate the file? I do not have mysql server installed (nor do I want to) as I connect out to a different server.

Many Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Why do you want to access a `mysql.sock` file on your system if you don't run mysql on it? The `sock` file is an alternative way to connect to a **local** mysql server instead of using `ip` and `port` (you for sure could create an own `socket` file and pipe the request to a remote mysql server, but this normally does not really make sense).

Comment: I think you want the mysql.sock to access an external mysql. If is that what you want, your assumption is incorrect. You just need the library, driver to access the mysql. In php just use the mysql functions. Usually the php already have the mysql driver installed. If not, take a look on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

The mysql.sock file will be created by the mysql server when it's running. If the mysql.sock file is missing, the mysql server isn't running.

Comment: Or.. The sock file is generated on a different designated location :)

Comment: @dbf well cause of the `I do not have mysql server installed(nor do I want to)` it is most likely that mysql server is not running ;)